# How to update React state with a data object using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with a date picker and a would like to change the value of the date picker in the state, using hooks, and also the date in the date picker itself, so you can select a date, or you can click a button to set a date, like 30 days ago.

this is what I tried so far:

```
const MyComp = () => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    dateFrom: new Date(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    dateTo: new Date()
  });

  const handleDateClick = interval => {
    setFormData({...formData, dateFrom: new Date(Date.now() - interval * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)});
    setFormData({...formData, dateTo: new Date()});
  };

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => handleDateClick(30)} variant="secondary">30 days ago</Button>

    <DatePicker
      selected={formData.dateFrom}
      name="dateFrom"
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy"
      onChange={value => handleOnChange({target: {name: "dateFrom", value}})}
    />
);

}
```

clicking the button has no effect, not even displaying any error, the state is not updated and the value in the datepicker does not change? Any idea please?

Comment: Can you give a sandbox code so that i can look into it.

Comment: Does the `onClick` handler gets triggered at all? Meaning does `handleDateClick` get called when you click the button?

Comment: How can we guess from where `DatePicker` comes from? How it implemented? Which library is it?

Comment: @goto yes handleDateClick is triggered and I can console.log(interval) and see the value

Comment: @DennisVash this is really not important, the important thing is to update the state, the the datepicker will display the value

Comment: I just tried this example and it works.

Comment: @goto1 maybe because the button is passing 7 and 7 is in the state? try onClick={() => handleDateClick(30).

Comment: I mean I keep clicking the button and the state changes no problem. I get something like the following - `{"dateFrom":"2020-02-07T17:57:08.918Z","dateTo":"2020-02-14T18:04:39.571Z"}`

Comment: it is only the dateTo changing I suppose. I think the line not working is ```setFormData({...formData, dateFrom: new Date(Date.now() - interval * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)});```

Comment: You're setting it to the same date.

Comment: Both are changing - you are using `new Date()` which will always yield a different result every time you click, plus you're changing both values in the state.

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully now is more clear.

Comment: It just hit me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing a strange behavior is because your `handleDateClick` is calling `setFormData` twice in a row, which is a problem because `setFormData` it is asynchronous, meaning that it will not immediately reflect and update your state.

See this SO question for more details:

- [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

So, essentially what ends up happening is that you update `dateFrom` but then call `setFormData` again right after, and since it uses **old state**, you're never seeing an updated value for `dateFrom`.

```js
const handleDateClick = interval => {
  setFormData({ ...formData, dateFrom: ... })

  // uses the value of `dateFrom` from the "old state"
  // when you do `...formData`, then updates `dateTo`
  setFormData({ ...formData, dateTo: ... })
}
```

I suggest you combine all your updates inside `handleDateClick` into a single `setFormData` call. From what it looks like, there's no reason for you to have two separate calls.

Here's how you should approach this instead:

```js
function Button({ children, ...rest }) {
  return <button {...rest}>{children}</button>;
}

function MyComp() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    dateFrom: new Date(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    dateTo: new Date()
  });

  const handleDateClick = interval => {
    setFormData({
      dateTo: new Date(),
      dateFrom: new Date(Date.now() - interval * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => handleDateClick(30)}>Click me!</Button>
      <p>
        <b>State:</b> {JSON.stringify(formData)}
      </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a working example if you'd like to see:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cori-iuwxh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)